Filter a pandas row if it is significantly larger than neighbours given that it starts with specific character
I have a dataframe like this
                        Name  Year      Value
0                     Mexico  1961      14357
1                     Mexico  1961      15161
2                     Mexico  1961     514658
3                     Mexico  1962      15559
4   United States of America  1977    2191197
5   United States of America  1978    2470734
6   United States of America  1978   52470734
7   United States of America  1979    2737377
8   United States of America  1979   52731457
9   United States of America  1980    3029030
10  United States of America  1980   53024589
11  United States of America  1981    3272565
12  United States of America  2010   15199150
13  United States of America  2010  515543018
14  United States of America  2011   15861873
15  United States of America  2011   16250364

I want to convert it to:
                        Name  Year     Value
0                     Mexico  1961     14357
1                     Mexico  1961     15161
2                     Mexico  1961     14658
3                     Mexico  1962     15559
4   United States of America  1977   2191197
5   United States of America  1978   2470734
6   United States of America  1978   2470734
7   United States of America  1979   2737377
8   United States of America  1979   2731457
9   United States of America  1980   3029030
10  United States of America  1980   3024589
11  United States of America  1981   3272565
12  United States of America  2010  15199150
13  United States of America  2010  15543018
14  United States of America  2011  15861873
15  United States of America  2011  16250364

As you can see when the last column was significantly larger than its neighbours, it it replaced by a different number which is just removal of 5 from its front.
for example for Mexico, in 3rd row 514658 is replaced by 14658, firstly because 514658 is significantly(5x-10x) larger than its neighbours ie 15161 and 15559.
Similarly for USA,
United States of America,1979,52731457
is replaced by
United States of America,1979,2731457
Similarly

United States of America,1978,52470734

United States of America,1980,53024589

United States of America,2010,515543018


are replaced by

United States of America,1978,2470734

United States of America,1980,3024589
and

United States of America,2010,15543018
respectively.


But mind you,

firstly the first column ie Name should exactly match,
secondly the last column ie Value has to start with 5 and
finally Value has to be significantly larger ie with mostly one digit more than neighbours to avoid risk of removing false positives.

By now you might have understood this is a data cleaning exercise where some $ symbols have been written as 5 and hence have to be fixed.

You probably want to compare the previous or the next value, as if you only compare to the next one you will not be able to fix any errors that happen to be the last entry for that country.
So create a lag and lead column grouped by country using pandas.DataFrame.shift() and then create a Boolean mask of values to replace where:

The value starts with 5.
The value is at least 5 times larger than the previous value or next value.

Of course if you have countries with only one entry then this will not replace any values for that country.
df['lag'] = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].shift(1)
df['lead'] = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].shift(-1)
replace_val = (
    df['Value'].astype(str).str.startswith('5') & 
    (
        (df['Value'] > df['lag'] * 5) |
        (df['Value'] > df['lead'] * 5)
    )
)
df.loc[replace_val, 'Value'] = df.loc[replace_val, 'Value'].astype(str).str[1:].astype(int)
df.drop(["lag", "lead"], axis = 1, inplace=True)

Output:
                        Name  Year     Value
0                     Mexico  1961     14357
1                     Mexico  1961     15161
2                     Mexico  1961     14658
3                     Mexico  1962     15559
4   United States of America  1977   2191197
5   United States of America  1978   2470734
6   United States of America  1978   2470734
7   United States of America  1979   2737377
8   United States of America  1979   2731457
9   United States of America  1980   3029030
10  United States of America  1980   3024589
11  United States of America  1981   3272565
12  United States of America  2010  15199150
13  United States of America  2010  15543018
14  United States of America  2011  15861873
15  United States of America  2011  16250364

Data
data = {
    "Name": [ "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America", "United States of America" ],
    "Year": [ 1961, 1961, 1961, 1962, 1977, 1978, 1978, 1979, 1979, 1980, 1980, 1981, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011 ],
    "Value": [ 14357, 15161, 514658, 15559, 2191197, 2470734, 52470734, 2737377, 52731457, 3029030, 53024589, 3272565, 15199150, 515543018, 15861873, 16250364 ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

